# how to convert RS232 communication to TCP/IP communication

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a created hardware communicating application using RS232 protocol in MFC. But as there is problem regarding voltage signal strength, i would like to shift from RS232 to TCP/IP.

Can anyone help me on this topic...?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @RemyLebeau... I am having an microcontroller based card,which is connected to PC using RS232 communication wire and protocol used for communication is also RS232. Now i want change its communication protocol to TCP/IP, so can anyone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend the microcontroller board with a serial device server.

Known brands are Lantronix or Moxa, but there are many other options and manufacturers. For an "embedded" solution that is integrated on your board, the "Lantronix XPort" is a typical product. 
http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport.html

(I'm not affiliated with the Lantronix company.)

The Serial Device Server will connect to your RS232 on one end, and on its TCP/Ethernet side it offers usually a TCP server. It is usually configurable via network, through a built-in web interface, much like an Internet router.

Your PC application then needs to be changed as follows: Instead of opening a Windows COM port, you need to make a TCP client connection to that server, on a preconfigured TCP port. (Lantronix has 10001 as the default TCP port for this.)

But there is also special Windows driver software that lets you talk to your Serial Device Server / your microcontroller through a "virtual COM port". This is sometimes the best solution for legacy PC applications, where you cannot change the original code and have to use a Windows COM port. For a MFC application this might be a good choice.

Comment: Actually i don`t want to add any extra hardware component between PC and card.we are also going to do changes in the micro-controller for TCP-IP communication